# Error Installing OpenCV on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, opencv

I have been trying to install OpenCV on my Raspberry Pi with Python 3. I have followed this tutorial http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-opencv/ and when I get to the make command it gets to around 14 percent and stops because of an error. Can anyone help me install OpenCV?

Comment: Have you checked around the Exchange for other's similar problems and solutions? I can see related question right now beside this question.

Comment: I have looked around but they are not having the same problem as me

Comment: What is the error message that is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing OpenCV is pretty much straightforward process, it just take a lot of time. mitchtech is a good source but it is for old Raspbian not for the new ones. I googled a lot for the last few months to make a cheat sheet, and I made one. You can download my [cheat sheet](https://github.com/Tes3awy/OpenCV-3.0.0-Compiling-on-Raspberry-Pi-2-) and try it out. I recommend you install OpenCV for Python 2 not 3, and I also recommend that you stick to the cheat sheet especially in step 12. Sometime when you use all the cores the process fails to continue. I also recommend you use a 2A, 5V Adapter. If it works for you please accept my answer.

Comment: Why do you recommend using Python 2 over 3?

Comment: @Loanb222   NumPY, matplotlib, SciPY, and other packages doesn't have much of documentation on the internet for Python 3. most of Python used on the internet is Python 2.7.x win32. So If you always need help in your first time programming on Pi, I recommend you use Python 2.

Comment: Do you know of any good tutorials about OpenCV?

Comment: @ user3557707 Yes I know a lot but my favorite and the easiest is [sentdex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z78zbnLlPUA&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDdttJXlLtAJxJetJcqmqlQq). Also I am working on some and once I upload them on YouTube I will comment here.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to install OpenCV on on Raspberry pi is to use:

```
sudo apt install python3-opencv
```

instead of pip. As suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/60237868/9697329